# NFS multiples NIC

Tags: linux, nfs4

I have install nfs server into Ubuntu Hirsute, using two NIC, like that:

```
/nfs    172.16.0.0/24(fsid=0,rw,insecure,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/nfs    172.18.0.0/24(fsid=0,rw,insecure,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/nfs/share1 172.16.0.0/24(rw,insecure,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/nfs/share1 172.18.0.0/24(rw,insecure,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

In the client side, I have mounted the share like this:

```
mount -t nfs4 172.16.0.100:/nfs /mnt/ -o async,auto,exec,_netdev,nodev,rw,retry=5,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,proto=tcp,hard,intr
mount -t nfs4 172.18.0.100:/nfs /mnt/ -o async,auto,exec,_netdev,nodev,rw,retry=5,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,proto=tcp,hard,intr
```

As you can see I have mounted twice in the same directory. i.e, /nfs

When I put down the NIC which holds the 172.16.0.100 address, in the client side I still can ls into the /nfs directory. So I check that work with the second interface online and the first offline. Then I brought the first interface on line again.
However, when I put down the NIC which holds the 172.18.0.100 address, in the client side the mounted nfs share hangs, and I no longer can access the /nfs directory.

What I doing wrong here??

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

With mounting as in your example

```
mount -t nfs4 172.16.0.100:/nfs /mnt/ ...
mount -t nfs4 172.18.0.100:/nfs /mnt/ ...
```

you mount server `172.18.0.100` on top of `172.16.0.100`. **NOTE**: This is not using both NICs, this is mounting two different servers into a single directory. The last mount wins, e.g. visible. Thus by switching off `172.16.0.100` nothing happens, as it not used anyway.

As linux  mount command (and NFS client) doesn't supports multiple servers, you should use [NIC bonding](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO_BONDING) if you want redundancy
of aggregated bandwidth.